# How to send messages using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a template for a messaging app to use for a project but I don't know how to incorporate the JavaScript to make this template work. At the bare minimum I want to send messages. How can I do this?

Code that I currently have:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,700');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #b5b5b7;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container{
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 1rem 2rem 4rem rgba(0,0,0,2);
  min-width: 60rem;
}

.users,
#chat-screen{
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 30rem;
}

.users{
  background-color: black;
}

#chat-screen{
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(242,182,50,0.85), rgba(242,182,50,0.85)), url("space.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.users header{
  background-color: #677077;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.users ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.users ul li{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.1);
}

.user ul li:nth-last-child{
  border-bottom: none;
}

.users header h1{
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.avatar img{
  width: 7.5rem;
  height: 7.6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.users .avatar{
  display: flex;
  margin: auto 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.username{
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.online{
  background-color: #4ad99b;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6.5rem;
  bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.offline{
  background-color: #fa676a;
}

.away{
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.busy{
  background-color: purple;
}

.invisible{
  background-color: dimgray;
}

.users ul li .online{
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.users-list{
  flex-grow: 2;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.text{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.timestamp{
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  flex-grow: 0.3;
  margin: auto 0;
}

#chat-screen{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 2;
  color: #333;
}

#chat-screen .msg-compose{
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#chat-screen .msg-compose textarea{
  flex-grow: 2;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  height: 2rem;
}

#chat-screen .msg-compose textarea:focus{
  outline: none;
}

#chat-screen .msg-compose i{
  color: #c0c0c0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#messages{
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow: 2;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#messages article{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

#messages article .avatar{
  margin-right: 0;
}

#messages .right .avatar{
  margin-right: 0;
}

.msg{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.msg .pointer{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1rem 1.5rem 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.inner-msg {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.right{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.right .msg{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.right .msg .pointer{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1.5rem 1rem 0 0;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.right .msg .inner-msg{
  border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<section id="chat-screen">
  <section id="messages">
    <div id="chatHistory">
    <article>
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="Bert.jpg" alt="Bert">
      </div>
      <div class="msg">
        <div class="pointer"></div>
          <div class="inner-msg">
            <p>Lucky...I wish I had that</p></div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="right">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="Audrey.jpg" alt="Audrey">
      </div>
      <div class="msg">
        <div class="pointer"></div>
          <div class="inner-msg">
            <p>It's called spend money fam!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="Bert.jpg" alt="Bert">
      </div>
      <div class="msg">
        <div class="pointer"></div>
          <div class="inner-msg">
            <p>But I'm a broke College Student :(</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="right">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="Audrey.jpg" alt="Audrey">
      </div>
      <div class="msg">
        <div class="pointer"></div>
          <div class="inner-msg">
            <p>I'm right there with you on that one V_V</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="Bert.jpg" alt="Bert">
      </div>
      <div class="msg">
        <div class="pointer"></div>
          <div class="inner-msg">
            <p class="text">Struggle Squad Unite :P</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="msg-compose">
    <i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Something Here..." name="message-to-send" id="message-to-send">
    <button type="submit" id="button"><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
  </div>

</section>
```

I just want to be able to at least send messages. But I know that I need something like Python or Java to be able to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Answer (score 0):

The project is looking awesome! Yes you'll need some javascript to handle the user input from

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Something Here..." name="message-to-send" id="message-to-send">
```

I suggest looking at something like **document.getElementById("message-to-send")** to start handling input. 
Good luck!

Comment: So I have something with document.getElementById but i suppose I'm not using it correcty? Here's what I got:                                                                                   const messages = document.getElementById("msg-compose");
  const textbox = document.getElementById("message-to-send");
  const button = document.getElementById("button");

  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const newMessage = document.createElement("p");
    newMessage.innerHTML = textbox.value;
    messages.appendChild(newMessage);
    textbox.value = "";
  });

Comment: And what is your output?